# Mysterious optional variant parameter for SendKeys() method of Wscript.Shell COM object

Tags: powershell, shell, com, sendkeys

I know `SendKeys()` is evil, unreliable, and an absolute last resort when no other automation technique exists. I avoid it whenever possible and have no immeidate need for it. But I noticed something when using the `wsript.shell` object for shortcut creation. `Get-Member` revealed the definition for `SendKeys` to be `void SendKeys (string, Variant)`. Here's the quickest way to see for yourself:

```
(New-Object -com wscript.shell).sendkeys
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> (New-Object -com wscript.shell).sendkeys

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void SendKeys (string, Variant)
```

None of the MS docuemtation I've found mentions the `Variant` parameter. When I search for that definition string, the only results I've gotten are captures of `Get-Member` or similar listings of methods, but nowhere have a I seen an explantion or example. I know a lot (if not all) of COM menthods can be traced back to an often more powerful interface, but I don't know where `SendKeys` "comes from". Hoping someone here has the deeper background that can reveal the mystery.

Comment: It's a relatively recent addition (old doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8c6yea83(v=vs.85)) . The type library tells us it's named "wait". And a bit of disassembling tells us it's expecting a boolean argument, so I guess it instructs the SendKeys to wait for completion or something

Comment: Thanks. Just tested with both boolean & interger arguments sneding to Notepad. All returned a value of `True`! Doesn't look like a `Void` to me! So maybe any value for the parameter is essentially calling the [`SendWait()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Don't now about that powershell return value but wscript.Shell.SendKeys is indeed void. And no, the code doesn't use winforms' SendWait, it's a specific code based on keybd_event https://i.imgur.com/O3P3f40.png (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) but it may be an equivalent of SendWait when you use true as a 2nd parameter